# Please do not force me out the frame

Tags: feature-request

I usually access StackOverflow from Reddit with Reddit toolbar. (Every link is opened inside a frame with toolbar on top.) But StackOverflow doesn't allow framing.

It's fine. It's even nice enough to say "click OK to remove the frames." Problem is that there is no other button than OK.

Let me press cancel and not see the web page at all. Even better, give me an HTML link so I can open it on a new tab or new window.

Comment: I too use the Reddit frame toolbar, and find this annoying.


The alert should be removed; it steals focus, is modal, and makes it really annoying when framed-SO is visited in a background tab, at least in Firefox v3.6.


Instead the body should be replaced with a message saying that SO will not be framed and include a link to break out.  This would also allow users to keep the frame visible but open the content in a new tab.


Flickr does this, and it's a good example of making frame busting less annoying.

Comment: I agree that there should be a way to decline the framebreaker, even if it means the page doesn't get visited. By that token, forcing you to go along with the framebreak may be a business decision.